# whereBetween in Laravel not working well with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to query the users who created at 2016-01-10. So code in Laravel 5.1 like this (the created_at is timestamp):

```
$day1 = new Carbon();
$day1->year = 2016;
$day1->month = 1;
$day1->day = 10;

$day2 = new Carbon();
$day2->year = 2016;
$day2->month = 1;
$day2->day = 11;

User::whereBetween('created_at', [$day1->startOfDay(), $day2->startOfDay()])->get();
```

The codes above works fine.
But this normal way, does not:

```
User::whereBetween('created_at', [$day1->startOfDay(), $day1->endOfDay()])->get();
```

I don't think there is a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a between for this:

```
$myDate = new Carbon('2016-01-10');
User::whereDate('created_at', '=', $myDate->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But follow your code , I get this: "Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereDate() "

Comment: It should be `whereDate('created_at', '=',  $myDate)`, the second parameter must be the operator, which is this case is `=`.

Comment: No more error. With my first way, it would match 50 records. but with yours, nothing match. So how do I fix this problem? The created_at column is timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @Schellingerht, with your formated code, it works. So, could you please explain why my first code works well but be failure with second?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like his

```
\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Line 902

User::whereDate('created_at', '=', new Carbon('2016-01-10'))->get();
```

And without Carbon

```
User::where( DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), '=', '2016-01-10')->get();
OR
$d = new Carbon('2016-01-10');
User::whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = ?', [$d])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to use Carbon. But with your code, nothing match, even I have nearly 50 records on that date. with my first code, it works, another would not.

Comment: The first condition using `where` the date equals the Carbon instance won't work if the column is of type DATETIME. And for the second there is a helper method `whereDate` that does the same thing but avoids using `DB::raw` as @Schellingerht pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Yes. the column is timestamp, so it doesn't work with the first way.

Comment: User::where('created_at', '=', (new Carbon('2016-01-10'))->format('Y-m-d'))->get();